# Moment of inertia of the Cavendish balance

Tags: newtonian-gravity, moment-of-inertia

In her paper, *Henry Cavendish: The man and the measurement*, Isobel Falconer uses, Newton's force equation as, $$\mu \theta = 4 G M m a / d^2$$ for the force that turns the arm 1 radian. Where does she get the factor of 4 and why $a$, the half-length of the pendulum enters this equation?

I copied her full analysis [here](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/falconer-analiz-02.html). And the entire paper can be found [here](http://cavendish-deneyi.com/pdf/henry-cavendish-the-man-and-the-measurement.pdf).

Comment: I must be having a hard time finding it because from what I can see this equation appears nowhere in the paper, where did she make this separate analysis? Cavendish did it by measuring the period of the pendulum, and I don't see that in her analysis.

Comment: She has it on page 475, in the link I provided, on a footnote.

Comment: Yep I see that now, I can't really go through it on mobile, hopefully someone comes along with some clarification for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the large spheres are moved from one side to the other, the rod swings through an angle $\theta$, but $\frac {\theta}{2}$ from the equilibrium position, line $L$

[image]

The torques acting on the rod to keep it in position $A$ were

$$\mu \frac{\theta}{2} = 2\frac{GMm}{d^2} \times a$$

where the $2$ on the right hand side is due to there being another pair of masses on the bottom left of the diagram, the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

When one big sphere is to the right of its neighbouring little sphere, and the other big sphere is to the left of its neighbouring little sphere, a couple is exerted on the torsion bar. The torque of the couple is
$$T=\text{magnitude of one force}\times \text{perpendicular separation of forces}$$
That is
$$ T=\frac{GMm}{d^2}2a$$
When the big spheres are on the other sides of the small spheres (but still with centres of neighbouring spheres distance $d$ apart), the torque is reversed. So the change in torque is
$$\Delta T=\frac{GMm}{d^2}4a$$
So if the torque per unit angle of twist in the suspension is $c$, the angle turned through because of the reversal of gravitational torque will be given at equilibrium by
$$c\theta=\frac{GMm}{d^2}4a.$$